# Factory Reset questions

Tags: windows, laptop, bios, toshiba-laptop, factory-defaults

### Factory Reset and Windows Reset questions

Okay, I get the basics of what these things do but I want to know more
I have **3** fairly simple questions I would like answered

**Firstly**, Factory Reset will also reset Bios right? Not just roll-back my OS and settings, if not is there a special way to reset the Bios?

**Secondly**, If I reset Windows will it delete the custom drivers installed by my manufacturer and replace them with generic Windows drivers?

**Thirdly** I would like to know how to Factory Reset my **Toshiba Satellite C55-B5101 Notebook**. I **do not have a disk** for it and I know some models have a setting to reset to Factory Defaults in the system somewhere
I.e. I had a Gateway that displayed Factory Reset as an option alongside the Windows reset
My only options on this notebook are to reset Windows. On my model of Toshiba, how do I access the Factory Reset option?

These questions may be a bit stupid but I would like to know this for clarification, thanks in advance, your support is greatly appreciated **:)**

**:Edit:**
I did actually try searching this stuff up but nothing I found clearly answered these questions.
Especially for the first 2

Comment: Please tell us which operating system, so we can provide a more useful answer.

Comment: It was preinstalled with Windows 8.1 but I am using Windows 10

Comment: I installed Windows 10 and it worked fine, I decided I wanted it to run like I got it fresh as windows 10 so I reset it to get rid of any unused and incompatible apps and programs
But....
At 99% it hung for around 4 hours then restarted with a blue screen saying INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE 
I couldn't boot into windows at all because of it

I concluded that the main reason was that it crashed just as it finished wiping everything, so there was no OS to boot into

I created install media to recover it and it kinda worked but I couldn't sync my email and updates kept failing

Comment: I decided to try again with the reset to fix the problems
It worked but since then I have noticed many problems
My computer turns off when it goes to sleep mode, and whenever I boot it. It shows the Toshiba logo then gives me a 40sec black screen then boots windows, I am missing all the Toshiba drivers as well and just have generic ones

Comment: I am guessing lots of things went wrong and I desperately need a factory reset
But I don't know how to do it on my model without a disk (Which I don't have)
I asked if it resets Bios because I think some settings in there could have gotten messed up

I plan to return it to Factory Defaults, Re-install Win10 then Reset Win10 to get a fresh OS and hope nothing bad happens again
But I wont reset again unless I know if this wont remove my Toshiba drivers because it happened before (But I am unsure if it is entirely because of the reset)

Comment: I am in quiet a bit of a pickle so I need to know this stuff for clarification before I start this process. Please help

Comment: Also, Will Factory Resetting fix all of the above problems?

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer your questions:

1.Factory reset will NOT reset the BIOS too, only your OS.You can only reset the BIOS by clearing the CMOS memory (there it stores the settings) or manually loading default settings when you are in the BIOS.

2.If you reset Windows, it will NOT replace the manufacturer drivers the laptop came with.

3.Windows does have a built-in factory reset function that will delete your personal data and keep only the OS. You can find in Settings > Update & Recovery > Recovery tab

Comment: How do I clear the CMOS memory?
And the only option there resets Windows 10
I wish for a full factory reset. All my manufacture drivers are gone and replaced with generic ones and I fear there could be more problems too, I want to take it back to it's out of box state

Comment: I recommend manually loading the default settings .It looks like [this](https://www.google.ro/search?q=windows+8+reset&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIo7Xh3rmbxwIVhG0UCh3SKwTq#tbm=isch&q=bios+default+settings&imgrc=yWFbc_MS1BG0EM%3A)

Comment: Also this is the page for your drivers >(http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200009386)

Comment: Okay and how do I do a full Factory Reset on my model of Toshiba without using a disk? The option isn't there

There are supposed to be 2 options, one is to reset the installed OS
And the other is to fully bring back the PC i.e. deleting newly downloaded drivers, installing manufacturer ones and rolling back to the original os of the computer

I know there must be some way to access this setting on Toshiba, I really need to know how

Comment: According to this guide i found > (http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Satellite-Laptops-all-other/Factory-Restore/td-p/258371 )  you should hold 0 (zero) key while you turn on your laptop until you get to a factory restore menu from toshiba. This will not work if you deleted the recovery partition on your laptop.Check out the entire page as you will see more methods of resetting it.

Comment: If the recovery metodh doesn't work, i reccomend you to download the Wnidows 10 iso image from Microsoft's [website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and burn it to a blank DVD.After that,save your important data and format all HDD partitions that you use, then reinstall Windows on the same partition it was installed. This is 100% problems-free.